# What are some actionable steps I can take to overcome my "Nice Guy Syndrome"

Tags: fear, anxiety

Basically this "Nice Guy Syndrome," as described by Dr. Robert Glover, refers to a pattern of behavior where individuals, often men, seek approval and avoid conflict by being overly nice, accommodating, and putting others' needs before their own. Ofthen, nice guys are seen as doormats/people pleasers and end up building resentment, unfulfillment, and difficulty in forming genuine connections.

From a Buddhist perspective, which teachings or principles can help in understanding and addressing the root causes of this syndrome? Furthermore and more importantly, what are practical, small, and specific steps that I can take to gradually overcome this pattern of behavior and develop healthier relationship dynamics? I know general mindfulness helps, and probably alone is enough to fix it overtime, but I am looking for something more doable and more direct.

Thanks for any answers

Comment: As a little bit Nice Guy Syndrome myself, I would like to see others answers too.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as something Buddhism can answer, and is also quite subjective.

Comment: But, in a nutshell, start listening to your own desires and needs as much as you listen to the desires and needs of others.

Comment: @Cdn_Dev It is a psychological condition that creates suffering - ultimately attachment and aversion to a set of specific things. As such Buddhism not only must have an answer, but the best and most effective answer.

Answer (score 1):

This has been my biggest problem, though I am in a committed relationship and have a steady job. It still causes stress despite getting past any major barriers towards the life you want.

I'll tell you how I've worked to resolve it, and  I will include Buddhist thought as well.

I believe the issue is that nice guys tend to give everyone equal amounts of honor. However, in the [Mahamangala Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/khp/khp.5.nara.html), the Buddha said that blessings come to us when we honor those who are worthy of honor, and we avoid foolish people. Amongst those worthy of honor are our parents, enlightened people, monks, and those we help in a peaceful occupation.

Furthermore, everybody is due basic respect, as that Sutta says, via just being generally patient, generous, and withstanding the ups and downs of life. I believe some Mahayana and Vajrayana suttas talk about everyone having Buddha nature, so that we ought be nice to everyone... however, it is the case that being overly respectful toward someone before they've earned it is almost like treating a fool and a stranger like they're our mother or father... and they not only will they take advantage of us, but then we can't even be in a good position to help others, or even the fool himself.

Here's where it gets tricky. What if we are nice to our parents, and yet our parents are bad to us? We probably should still respect them, as the Buddha even said respecting our parents is proof of having [integrity](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an02/an02.031.than.html). On the other hand, a parent might not get the 100% respect that a great parent would get if they are lousy. Perhaps only 99% then.

So... don't stop being nice. Just maybe be nicer to some people than others, and then people will seek your respect as opposed to them misusing it.

I think that mental shift of accepting that being nice is always correct, but that we can tone it down either a little bit or quite significantly depending on the situation, will help a lot.

Also, you mentioned actionable steps. I think some concrete steps can include things like self control. If someone says, "Hey, be a friend, get drunk with me", the monk might keep his simple life and decline, because he knows that a fool doesn't deserve honor in that way.

If an abusive ex wants to talk to you, instead of thinking, "I'll give her a bit of time, we have a history," there's also, "A history is important, but the abuse was also real. They don't deserve my time all things considered." And so on.

In Defensive driving courses they say the way to control the road is to control yourself. I think that is a way to work on Nice Guy Syndrome in accord with the Dharma.

*I'm editing to cite that I got the major part of this thesis from a Protestant pastor named John Piper, though the advice applies to Buddhist thought equally well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know. I could only speculate, maybe a problem is desire -- wanting to be liked, wanting something (reciprocal behaviour) in return? Or the fear, of the unpleasant consequences, of saying "no"?

A fix might be to concentrate on ethics -- what is "good" behaviour?
There's the behaviour in the Zen story *Is That So?* for example -- where the master's behaviour is, imo, ethical towards the child (rather than driven by a desire to be liked).

Conversely there is something to be said though, though I'm not sure what, for "unselfish" behaviour: it can be enlightening.